# What is the use of ("*") in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am reading jQuery, i don't know why use `("*")` please explain it's helpful

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $("*").hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Refer the Selectors stackoverflow documentaion http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jquery/389/selectors/4136/overview#t=2017040107020653041 And please refer the documentation before asking questions like this.

Comment: Why did you tagged Java for this question ?

Answer (score 2):

`*` is a selector in jquery which select everything without any condition including html, head and body.

Here is an example explaining its usage.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("*").hide();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Hello text
</div>
<button>Click Me to Hide everything</button>
```

* selector can be used with elements that it selects all child elements within the specified element. without any condition

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("div *").toggle();
    });
});
```

```css
div{
border:0.5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>Hello text</p>
  <a>Here is a link </a>
</div>

<button>Click Me to Hide/ Show elements inside the div</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(*)` is used to select all elements inside the document. Refer this: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_all.asp

Answer (score 0):

`$(*)` is a selector in jqueryto select all elements

and hence

`$("*").hide();` will hide all elements

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("*").hide();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Hello</div>
<p>World</p>
<span>Good Morning</span>
<button>Hide</button>
```

**[Docs](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)**