# what does "#id_name *" mean in jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I was making a search box using jquery when I came across the W3Schools answer and they used something like this

```
<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<div id="myDIV">
<p>I am a paragraph.</p>
<div>I am a div element inside div.</div>
<button>I am a button</button>
<button>Another button</button>
<p>Another paragraph.</p>
</div>


<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
   var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
   $("#myDIV *").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
   });
 });
});
```

I dont understand what is * in "#myDIV *" ?

here is the actual link of the page
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_filters.asp

Comment: it means get everything inside the element with the id mydiv - by the looks of your code, it gets all eleemts and then filters them on if they include the text that is entered into the input

Comment: * is for select all elements inside #myDiv. See this links for more information: https://api.jquery.com/all-selector/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the use of ("\*") in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43153792/what-is-the-use-of-in-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

It is a CSS selector that tells "select all".

In your case **select all inside div having** `id="myDIV"`

You can read about it on W3Schools too.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_all.asp

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery : **#xxx** means **id=xxx** . so **$("#myDIV")** menas get the element of id **myDIV**.

now come to * part : * is a **CSS Selector** ( which means "Select all elements ")
for more details check this link: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_all.asp

---

in your code : **$("#myDIV *")** means => get all the elemnts under div id **myDIV**.

Small example :

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('#mydiv *'))

console.log("------ if you want each of those elements under id mydiv ------")

document.querySelectorAll('#mydiv *').forEach (v => {
console.log(v)
})
```

```html
<div id=mydiv> 
  <p></p>
  <h2></h2>
  <input type="text" />
  <table> </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as native js - it mean `all nested elements in element with id myDiv`

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('#mydiv *'))
```

```html
<div id=mydiv> 
<input />
<b></b>
text
</div>
```